# My blade.php file is not recognized by PhpStorm anymore

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I have this `item_email.blade.php` that I created using PhpStorm. It was recognized as a blade file but today it suddenly turned into a plain text file.

I haven't changed anything there. I am not sure how to set it back to `blade.php` file. The suffix `blade.php` is still there. Nothing has changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Is it happening with ANY `.blade.php` file .. or with that file only? 2) If you create the same file (same name) in another folder -- will it behave the same? **P.S.** *"I haven't changed anything there"* not remembering making changes does not necessarily mean that you have not done them -- you most likely have not noticed how you did it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to go into Preferences -> Editor -> File Types -> Text and remove the item_email.blade.php from there.

add ext here:

```
*.blade.php
```

Comment: Accepted this because this works, but my answer also works.

Comment: +1, this is actually a much nicer fix than you know.. renaming files, especially when using version control – However it's find either way, I am happy we reached a conclusion <3

Answer (score 0):

Is it the only one?
Try to change its name to `item_email.blade.php_` and generate a new one and paste the contents in it and name it `item_email.blade.php`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Already did this, but the new also appears in plain text. I am afraid it has something to do with the name email being there.

Comment: Can you post the code so I can test it in my phpStorm?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name from `item_email.blade.php` to `item_emailview.blade.php`. This works.

I also tried to create a new `newitem_email.blade.php` which has exactly the same problem so we can safely assume that it is the `email` word there that confuses Phpstorm.

Comment: @LazyOne I have tried with 4 more files and they had the same problem, so it is repeatable.

Comment: The answer by ExohJosh is a correct one. I've seen and answered many questions like that myself -- should be around 10 of them just here on SO (plus maybe another 20+ elsewhere). So I believe I know a bit about this particular situation and how it can be fixed. Your answer is not a solution -- just a partial workaround-- open another project and try to create similarly named file there and you will have the same issue (assuming that you did not do what ExohJosh said).